# не могу повторно использовать переменную

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

есть функция:

```
function buildUser(first, last) {
    let fullName = first + " " + last;
    return {first, last, fullName};
}
```

я создаю переменные с помощью неё:

```
let {first, last, fullName} = buildUser("User1", "LastName");

console.log(first);
console.log(last);
console.log(fullName);
```

всё работает, но почему я не могу создать ещё одни переменные никак не пойму. делаю так:

```
let {first, last, fullName} = buildUser("test1", "test1");

console.log(first);
console.log(last);
console.log(fullName);
```

получаю синтаксическую ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: redeclaration of let first
let {first, last, fullName} = buildUser("test1", "test1");
```

если делаю с новыми переменнымы то они получаются undefined:

```
let {first2, last2, fullName2} = buildUser("test1", "test1");

console.log(first2);
console.log(last2);
console.log(fullName2);
```

что я упускаю , объясните пожалуйста?

совсем запутался:
такой код почему то не работает тоже:

```
function buildUser2 (first, last, postCount) {
    let fullNameMy = first + " " + last;
    const ACTIVE_POST_COUNT = 10;

    return {
        firstMy,
        lastMy,
        fullNameMy,
        isActive(){
            return postCount >= ACTIVE_POST_COUNT;
        }
    }
}

let {firstMy, lastMy, fullNameMy} = buildUser2("test2", "test2");

console.log(firstMy);
console.log(lastMy);
console.log(fullNameMy);
```

ошибка:

```
ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `firstMy' before initialization
```

Comment: Ответ и комментарии ниже хорошо отвечают на ваш вопрос. А с добавленным вопросом, вы возвращаете `firstMy` которые не объявлен в методе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в [операторе `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_let)

> Повторное объявление той же переменной в том же блоке или функции приведет к выбросу исключения SyntaxError.
>
> если делаю с новыми переменными то они получаются undefined:

```
let {first2, last2, fullName2} = buildUser("test1", "test1");

console.log(first2);
console.log(last2);
console.log(fullName2);
```

При [реструктуризирующем присваивании](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) важно имя полей.

В функции `buildUser` возвращается объект

```
return {first, last, fullName};
```

это [сокращенная форма объявления свойств объекта](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) эквивалентная

```
{
    "first": first,
    "last": last,
    "fullName": fullName,
}
```

В присваивании ожидается: `first2, last2, fullName2` в возвращаемом объекте их нет. поэтому они принимают значение по умолчанию: *undefined*

Проблем с именами свойств объектов можно избежать если возвращать из функции не объект а массив

```js
function buildUser(first, last) {
    let fullName = first + " " + last;
    return [first, last, fullName];
}


let [first, last, fullName] = buildUser("User1", "LastName");

console.log(first,last,fullName);

let [first2, last2, fullName2] = buildUser("test1", "test1");

console.log(first2, last2, fullName2);
```

#### Обновление:

ошибка:

```
ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `firstMy' before initialization
```

> В стандарте ECMAScript 2015 переменные, объявленный оператором let, переносятся наверх блока. Но если вы сошлетесь в блоке на переменную, до того как она будет объявлена оператором let, то это приведет к выбросу исключения ReferenceError, потому что переменная находится во "временной мертвой зоне" с начала блока и до момента ее объявления.

Comment: На второй его вопрос ещё нужно бы ответить)

Comment: А ну да все правильно, он же берет имена `first2, last2, fullName2`, которых нет в возвращаемом объекте

Comment: получается в таком варианте можно один раз использовать только функцию?

Comment: @stas0k Смотря что ты хочешь делать. Записывай в массив например. Либо возвращать массиов, как добавил в ответ Grundy

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я хотел несколько раз использовать так :  let {first, last, fullName} = buildUser("User1", "LastName"); let {first, last, fullName} = buildUser("User2", "LastName");

Comment: let не даст переинициализировать переменную. Используйте массивы тогда

Comment: @stas0k, в данном случае не принципиально возвращать именно объект, так как все равно используются только поля

Comment: благодарю, кажется очень сильно помогли мне!!